# Are there any English expressions that mean 'to lie a lot', and that include a 'that--clause' in their structure?

Tags: idiom-requests

I'd like to find an English expression, which is synonymous to, e.g., 'lie like a trooper', but with a *that-clause* in its structure i.e., *he lies (so much) that + idiomatic expression*. For example, in German, a corresponding expression with a *dass-clause* is 'lügen, dass sich die Balken biegen'
"Er lügt, dass sich die Balken biegen" ("Er lügt sehr")

Note: 'that' is not necessarily overt. An expression with a similar structure is '(that) one could cut it with a knife', as in 'The smoke was so thick (that) you could cut it with a knife.', to imply a *very thick smoke*).

Comment: Hi, thanks! Therefore, if I understand it right, people would say in English 'to lie that one can’t keep track of their lies'

Comment: People are said in English to *lie like a rug*.

Comment: We don't say "lie heavily" to mean "tell many lies". Probably because "to lie heavily" would mean "to recline with one's weight otherwise unsupported". This is why the comment by  @Mazura is a pun.

Comment: I grew up in the country. We used to say "lie like a dog" @Mazura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common saying here (US, SE Region):

> He lies so much (that) he's beginning to believe himself.

Using *starting* (instead of *beginning*) is more common in rural areas, I would say.

> He lies so much (that) he's starting to believe himself.

Also, another common saying with *has lied* (with *them* referring to the lies that he's told):

> He's lied so much (that) he's lost track of them.

Lastly, a very common saying with *so long* (instead of *so much*):

> He's lied for so long (that) he's forgotten the truth.

I would say that my first example is the most region specific. The other two examples are easily found online, in some form (USA).